# Why Magento Cloud doesn't show product's image in the admin, but showing it in the frontend?

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento-cloud

I'm adding product images in the admin panel, but after save it's not showing the image in the backend.
The result is 200 and opening it in a new window the image is blank, what could I do?

[image: Magento 2 Cloud, no image in the backend]

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the details you provided and the screenshot.

Fastly IO is turned on, but it looks like **your Screenshot** has a response header:

```
fastly-io-error: not a supported image format
```

- What is your source image format?
- Does it have valid image data? (some corrupted images returns responses like this)

I think that would be a good place to start the investigation.

---

Furthermore, when I checked it in my sandbox, It should render like below.

- Fastly IO is turned ON: Header `fastly-stats: 1`
- Fastly IO info is valid: `fastly-io-info: ifsz=*** ...`

[image]